# Does std::string use the malloc (free, realloc etc) family of functions to allocate data?

Tags: c++, performance, malloc, std, stdstring

Consider this implementation of a custom string class append operator:

```
inline string& operator+=(const string& rhs){
            if(rhs.size+(size-1)>capacity) {
                data = static_cast<char8_t *>(realloc(data, capacity+=rhs.capacity));
            }

            //culprit???
            memcpy((data + size - 1), rhs.data,rhs.size);
            
            size+=rhs.size;
            return *this;
}
```

where data is the dynamically allocated memory and size and capacity are member variables. Looks pretty standard right? I tried benchmarking this against std::string like so:

```
std::string test_a,test_b; test_a = "efjrpojgerojoejr"; test_b = "1204r94f3212345";
    unsigned long long average_std = 0;
    unsigned long long average_custom = 0;
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
            std::string a(test_a);
            std::string b(test_b);

            auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
            a += b;
            auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
            std::cout << a << std::endl;
            average_std+= (stop - start).count();
        }
    }
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
            custom::string a(test_a);
            custom::string b(test_b);
            auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
            a += b;
            auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
            std::cout << a << std::endl;
            average_custom += (stop - start).count();
        }
    }
    std::cout << ((double)(average_custom/1000000))/((double)(average_std/1000000)) << std::endl;
```

std::string is consistently ~50% faster. Thinking that the culprit might be memcpy, I commented it out completely(which obviously makes the append fail) but it made no difference to runtime. So my conclusion is that realloc is the culprit here(the example I used to benchmark is such that both std::string and custom::string reallocate). I tried making sense of the library code but I didn't get very far there.  So what voodoo magic does std::string to allocate so fast? A pre-allocated block of memory or something? Note this was on clang 12.0.0 on an intel macbook with -O3 optimization.

Comment: Yes, they do use `malloc` and `free` indirectly through `new[]` and `delete[]` but most string implementations have small string optimizations which your implementation doesn't seem to have

Comment: most `std::string` implementations use SSO, so for shortish strings there may be no allocation at all.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ah yes that makes perfect sense. So if I understand correctly there is a central char[] buffer kept on stack and each string instance gets to use a part of this buffer until it exceeds a certain size? Or does each string instance have its own char[]?

Comment: each string has its own char[]

Comment: With `capacity+=rhs.capacity`, you are allocating more memory than you strictly need. Not sure how much it matters for this particular test; it's not clear how much larger `capacity` is than `size` for particular strings involved.

Comment: To avoid the effects of small string optimization, simply make your "seed" strings longer; say 100 characters each. That would definitely force `std::string` to store data on the heap.

Comment: @arc31 - look at: `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/string`, and search the source for `min_cap` - the surrounding code gives some idea of how   the size of an array member of `value_type [=char]` is determined for the `basic_string<_CharT>` specialization.

Comment: @arc31 - standard library headers are very difficult to follow, but it's also worth considering that the default `Allocator` could be tuned for string performance too. But as others have pointed out - try setting `a`, `b` to a few kilobytes in length and see how it compares...

Comment: @arc31 Why are you subtracting -1 from `size`? Are you counting the null terminator in the `size`? That would be unusual for a string class to do. Do allocate room for it, but don't count it. Also, you are not accounting for the possibility of `realloc()` failing. If It does, your code will leak the original `data` memory. The standard `std::string `class throws an exception if it can't allocate memory.

Comment: There is also no realloc with new/delete and the strings own copy mechanism might take advantage of better alignment than realloc can, meaning fewer branches.

Comment: The actual answer is "it's up to the implementation". `std::string` is a specialisation of a templated class named `std::basic_string`, and one of the template parameters is an allocator type. The default allocator (that standard library provides and that standard containers, including `basic_string`, use by default) uses `new`/`delete` expressions to allocate/release objects, which in turn call one of the overloads of `operator new()`/`operator delete()` to allocate/deallocate memory - and those functions MAY (the standard doesn't actually require them to) use `malloc()` and `free()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau This isn't the actual code, the size variable is actually a variable in a  dynamic container inside the string class, this was just to demonstrate in a simple way. You're totally right on realloc though

Comment: @BrettHale Yep, now the speed difference shows up. std seems to be ~20 percent slower. Still kind of odd that they sacrificed memory savings and some speed for larger strings to make performance on small strings faster(where speed isn't generally the top priority anyways)

Comment: @arc31 - the standard library will be using `operator new (size)` if you dig deep enough into the allocator, with the expectation that a failure preserves the state and throws a `std::bad_alloc`. There's no `realloc` variant for C++ dynamic memory management - so you need to allocate storage to hold the combined strings, copy `a`, `b` into this memory, and *then* release `a` and `b`... requiring more memory and more work. It can't take advantage of an optimized `realloc` in the C library.

Comment: Note that `data = static_cast<char8_t *>(realloc(data, ...))` potentially leaks memory. If the attempted reallocation fails `realloc` returns a null pointer, and this code overwrites the original value of `data` with that null pointer, leaving no apparent way to release the original memory block.